# Как записать выражение в значение свойства объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Инициализирую объект:

```
const myObject = {
    a: 20,
    b: 20,
    sum: myObject.a + myObject.b
};
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Cannot access 'myObject' before initialization

Как это сделать правильно?

Понимаю, что можно поступить следующим образом:

```
const myObject = {
    a: 20,
    b: 20
};

myObject.sum = myObject.a + myObject.b;
```

Есть ли возможность произвести вычисления сразу же при инициализации объекта?

upd:
Извините за опечатку, сумма конечно же через плюс вычисляется:

> sum: myObject.a + myObject.b

Comment: В объекте: `sum: function() { return this.a * this.b }`. Ну а потом чтобы получить: `myObject.sum()`

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, это действительно настолько просто, спасибо. У меня уже крышу потихоньку плавит конечно на ночь глядя, кажется нужно пойти поспать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, так напрямую не обратиться и даже `this.a` и `this.b` будут недоступны, но есть один обходной пусть с помощью `get`, который так же не позволит положить туда произвольное значение, пока не объявите и не вызовете соответсвующий метод `set`:

```js
const myObject = {
    a: 20,
    b: 20,
    get sum () {return this.a + this.b},
    get multiply () {return this.a * this.b}
};

console.log(myObject);
console.log(myObject.sum);
console.log(myObject.multiply);
```

Comment: Очень интересно, ранее не встречал таких приемов, буду изучать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myObject = {
    a: 20,
    b: 20,
    sum: () => myObject.a * myObject.b
};
console.log(myObject.sum())
myObject.a = 10
console.log(myObject.sum())
```

Так будет работать, а вот правильность такого вызывает вопросы)
Возможно, вам пригодится https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy

Comment: Как же это просто, мне стыдно за свою тупость. А почему правильность такого вызывает вопросы?
Про прокси интересно, буду изучать обязательно.